# Select highest count in a multiple group by query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am working on a ping pong scoreboard and trying to get the winner of each month. My current query looks like this:

`` SELECT COUNT(winner) as wins, winner as player, YEAR(recorded) as year, MONTH(recorded) as month FROM `matches` GROUP BY winner, YEAR(recorded), MONTH(recorded) ``

And this is the result of that query:

```
+------+--------+------+-------+
| wins | player | year | month |
+------+--------+------+-------+
|    7 |     21 | 2021 |     1 |
|    4 |     19 | 2021 |     1 |
|    1 |     20 | 2021 |     1 |
|   78 |     20 | 2021 |     2 |
|   46 |     19 | 2021 |     2 |
|   84 |     21 | 2021 |     2 |
|    4 |     23 | 2021 |     2 |
|    2 |     26 | 2021 |     2 |
|    5 |     20 | 2021 |     3 |
|    9 |     21 | 2021 |     3 |
|    9 |     20 | 2021 |     4 |
|   10 |     21 | 2021 |     4 |
|    8 |     19 | 2021 |     4 |
+------+--------+------+-------+
```

I want to get the highest count of each month of the year so the result will look like this:

```
+------+--------+------+-------+
| wins | player | year | month |
+------+--------+------+-------+
|    7 |     21 | 2021 |     1 |
|   84 |     21 | 2021 |     2 |
|    9 |     21 | 2021 |     3 |
|   10 |     21 | 2021 |     4 |
+------+--------+------+-------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: use the result as basis, but you didn't topd u swhat to do when a wo with the same number. Also a full ]mre] would also help

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a version of mysql with CTEs available (which would include 8.0.23), I would consider using your existing query like:

```
WITH myquery AS
(
 SELECT COUNT(winner) as wins, winner as player, YEAR(recorded) as year, MONTH(recorded) as month FROM `matches` GROUP BY winner, YEAR(recorded), MONTH(recorded)
)
SELECT m1.*
FROM myquery m1 LEFT OUTER JOIN myquery m2
  ON m1.year = m2.year AND m1.month = m2.month AND m2.wins > m1.wins
WHERE m2.player IS NULL
```

The simply joins your query to itself and returns results where it can't match a record with the same month/year and higher wins.

Without CTEs, you could actually repeat the query:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(winner) as wins, winner as player, YEAR(recorded) as year, MONTH(recorded) as month FROM `matches` GROUP BY winner, YEAR(recorded), MONTH(recorded)
) m1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
 SELECT COUNT(winner) as wins, winner as player, YEAR(recorded) as year, MONTH(recorded) as month FROM `matches` GROUP BY winner, YEAR(recorded), MONTH(recorded)
) m2
 ON m1.year = m2.year AND m1.month = m2.month AND m2.wins > m1.wins
WHERE m2.player IS NULL
```

Another option is probably to do the following which uses a `row_number` window function to assign an ordering value to each group, which the outer query selects against.

```
SELECT wins, player, year, month
FROM
(
 SELECT wins, player, year, month, row_number(PARTITION BY year, month ORDER BY wins DESC) rn
 FROM
 (
  SELECT COUNT(winner) as wins, winner as player, YEAR(recorded) as year, MONTH(recorded) as month FROM `matches` GROUP BY winner, YEAR(recorded), MONTH(recorded)
 ) a 
) b
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like my MySQL version is not compatible with CTEs as I am getting a "Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)" error.

Comment: The alternative to CTE worked perfectly. Thank you very much.